# Covariant Taylor series

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

I am reading the following lecture notes of Avramidi 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255565392_Analytic_and_geometric_methods_for_heat_kernel_applications_in_finance

I want to understand the covariant taylor series part (page 87). Let $f$ be a scalar function on a Riemannian manifold. We have the Taylor series

$$f(x(t))=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}t^n\left[\frac{d^n}{d\tau^{n}}f(x(\tau))\right]_{\tau=0}$$
Here $x(t)$ describes a geodesic from $x(0)=x'$ and $x(t)=x$. Now we have that $\frac{d}{d\tau}=\dot{x}(\tau)\nabla_{i}$ and the geodesic equation $\dot{x}^{i}\nabla_{i}\dot{x}^{j}=0$ ($\nabla$ is the Levi Cevita connection). Then he claims
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}t^n\dot{x}^{i_{1}}(0)...\dot{x}^{i_{n}}(0)[\nabla_{(i_{1}}...\nabla_{i_{n})}f](x')$$
The parantheses denote symmetrization. [...] denotes the value inside when $x\rightarrow x'$

Where does this symmetrization comes from? For me it is not necessary.

Comment: Even if not necessary, it's not wrong. The anti-symmetric part should cancel, so the extra terms you are talking about should sum to zero.

Comment: But is it necessary? And why should the antisymmetric part cancel?

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268249/2451

Answer (score 2):

One obtains that formula with $\nabla_{i_1} \dots \nabla_{i_1} f$ (no symmetrization), but the object $\nabla_{i_1} \dots \nabla_{i_1} f$ splits into a symmetric and an antisymmetric part. The antisymmetric part is contracted with the obviously symmetric object $\dot x ^{i_1} (0) \dots \dot x ^{i_n} (0)$, and the result vanishes because it is a general combinatorial fact (no differential geometry needed) that the contraction of a symmetric object and an antisymmetric one vanishes. Therefore, the only surviving part of $\nabla_{i_1} \dots \nabla_{i_1} f$ is the symmetric one.